# Google maps not working with ocLazyLoading in subequent request

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, hybrid, oclazyload

I am having an issue with google maps with ocLazyLoading receiving an error message **"You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors"**. I am using ocLazyLoading to Load all dependencies whenever it is required to improve page load performance.

Google maps work for first request but in subsequent request to same page causing the error saying **"You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page"** and maps does not shows up.

Following is the code used to resolve the dependencies with ocLazyLoad. Just for information I am using Angular UI-router for routing and it is a Hybrid mobile app with IONIC framework.

```
.state('abstractpage.page1',  {  
      cache: false,
      url: "/page1/{param}",
      views: {
          'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: "views/page1.html",
              controller: "page1ctrl"
          }
      },
      resolve: {
          loadMap: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
              return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                  serie: true,
                  files: [
                    'js!https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
                    'scripts/shared/markerwithlabel.js',
                    'scripts/shared/markercluster_compressed.js',
                    'libs/infobox.js'
                  ]
              })
          }]
      }
  })
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not loading the `Google Maps API` either in the `HTML` or in one of those other `js` libraries?

Comment: Yes, I am sure there is no reference of google api except in router